# Reading weight from Weighing scale

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read weight from a weighing scale (BLE device) through bluetooth using my android app. I am able to connect to it and retrieve the services and characterstics with the given UUIDs(from the official documentation). But not sure how to read the weight value. In the documentation they have also mentioned that I have to pass some commands to read the values from the weighing scale. I am not sure how to pass the commands to the weighing scale through bluetooth. Please help me in this regard, thanks in advance.

Comment: which weight scale ? and have they provides any sdk for interaction ?

Comment: Hi Vinay, it is a weight scale from Ohaus Brand. They didn't give any SDK to interact. It is mentioned in the document that interaction has to be done through Bluetooth/BLE only

Comment: are you using Ohaus Scout SPX Bluetooth Interface ? or can u be more specific about the device

Comment: Hi Vinay, the model Number is Scout SPX8200,
If you can give me your mail id, I can even send you the given documentation also.

Comment: And yes, it is  Ohaus Scout SPX Bluetooth Interface

Comment: Mallik , i have done work on weighing scale and other bluetooth health devices , but i see that the device you are using does not have a sdk nor a developer support , i see on the internet that the only way to use that device is through the app they are providing , and they have not exposed any api to use it by 3rd party apps , i saw the doc also on net , i dont see any information on integration , you cannot interact with the device unless there are some wright byte code command  or read code command for that uuid device

Comment: Hi Vinay, We got some UUIDS and commands related to the device which are provided in the documentation. 
BluetoothGattDescriptor
00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
BluetoothGattService
2456e1b9-26e2-8f83-e744-f34f01e9d701
BluetoothGattCharacteristic
2456e1b9-26e2-8f83-e744-f34f01e9d703

IP - Immediate Print of displayed weight (stable or unstable).
P - Print displayed weight (stable or unstable).
and also if you give me your mail id, I can give you the document

Comment: if you give me your mail id, I can give you the document. If not let me know how to attach a document here

Answer (score 1):

Connect your bluetooth device and get an instance of inputstream to fetch data.
Or use this library. `https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary`